# Silhouette-Outlined Diffuse not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am using this shader: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse for my project.  I have noticed a few issues and was wondering if anyone else has come across this.

1. First, If I add the shader to a prefab manually, it works fine.  The issue is when I try to add it in my C# script.  This is true for both Build and Debug versions
2. My game is multiplayer. The script I use to add the shader works fine when  it runs in unity.  But, when it runs in a standalone app, it does not.  Instead of being outlined, the prefab is pink (like when you try to add a material that is not found/deleted).
3. Also, my code should only allow a specific player see the outline.  not all players.  But, for some reason, some see it (if its in Unity, they see it correctly, if not, they see the pink) while others do not.  My game can only have 4 players.

Here is my code:

```
private void playerDrawsTile(String playerName, ISFSArray cardsDealt, int drawPosition, string wall)
{
    Debug.Log("User " + playerName + " can draw tiles " + drawPosition);
    //if the player is the current players turn show the outline.            //otherwise show nothing
    if(sfs.MySelf.Id == getPlayer(playerName).Id)
    {
        GameObject[] getWall = new GameObject[36];
        //get the array of prefabs that contain the objects I want to  
        //add the shader to
        switch (wall)
        {
            case "EAST":
                getWall = controller.WallEast;
                break;
            case "SOUTH":
                getWall = controller.WallSouth;
                break;
            case "WEST":
                getWall = controller.WallWest;
                break;
            case "NORTH":
                getWall = controller.WallNorth;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        GameObject tile1 = GameObject.Find(getWall[drawPosition].name);
        GameObject tile2 = GameObject.Find(getWall[drawPosition + 18].name);

        Shader shader = Shader.Find("Outlined/Silhouetted Diffuse");
        Renderer rend = tile1.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.shader = shader;

        rend = tile2.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.shader = shader;

    }

}
```

This is done in C#.  The shader file is kept in Assets->projectFolder->Shaders folder.  I use the first shader in the Silhouette-Outline Diffuse page (not bumped or the others)

thanks

Comment: 'name': filter assets by their filename (without extension). Words separated by whitespace are treated as separate name searches. Use quotes for grouping multiple words into a single search.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html

Comment: Im  not sure how this might help?  As mentioned above, the shader script is found and works fine but only for the game running in Unity.  This seems to suggest Unity can find the asset.  It does not work for games running in their own environment (ie when I run the build file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found this thread that helped: 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/160922/shader-not-working-in-build.html

It was easy enough.  I just created a public variable of type Shader.  Then dropped my shader onto that variable and called it as needed.